# C++ - undefined reference to `mysql_init

Tags: c++

Here is my code executed on a Linux Ubuntu machine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "Logger.h"
#include "Config.h"
#include "mysql.h"


using namespace std;
int main() {
    shared_ptr<Config> config = make_shared<Config>("WorldServer");
    std::string def = "Nothing there.";
    unsigned int prot = 3306;
    Logger::Log( config->GetConfigValue("LoginDatabaseInfo", def));


        const char * host = config->GetConfigValue("LoginDatabase.MySQL.IP", def).c_str();
        const char * mysqlUser = config->GetConfigValue("LoginDatabase.MySQL.IP", def).c_str();
        const char * mysqlPassword = config->GetConfigValue("LoginDatabase.MySQL.IP", def).c_str();
        const char * mysqlDatabase = config->GetConfigValue("LoginDatabase.MySQL.IP", def).c_str();
        static unsigned int mysqlPort = config->GetConfigValue("LoginDatabase.MySQL.Port", prot);

        MYSQL *conn; /* pointer to connection handler */
        MYSQL_RES *res; /* holds the result set */
        MYSQL_ROW row;



        /* INITIALIZE CONNECTION HANDLER, DO NOT CHANGE */
        conn = mysql_init (NULL);

        /* THIS CONNECTS TO SERVER, DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING HERE */
        mysql_real_connect (conn, host, mysqlUser, mysqlPassword,
                            mysqlDatabase, mysqlPort, NULL, 0);
        /* show tables in the database (test for errors also) */
        mysql_query(conn, "SELECT * FROM accounts");
        res = mysql_store_result(conn);


        // get the number of the columns
        int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(res);
        // Fetch all rows from the result
        while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)))
        {
            // Print all columns
            for(int i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
            {
                // Make sure row[i] is valid!
                if(row[i] != NULL)
                    cout << row[i] << endl;
                else
                    cout << "NULL" << endl;

                // Also, you can use ternary operator here instead of if-else
                // cout << row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL" << endl;
            }
        }

        // DON'T FORGET TO CLEAN RESULT AFTER YOU DON'T NEED IT
        // ANYMORE

        if(res != NULL)
            mysql_free_result(res);

        /* disconnect from server */
        mysql_close (conn);

        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile I get the following error:

```
[ 83%] Linking CXX executable ../../../bin/AuthServer
CMakeFiles/AuthServer.dir/AuthServer.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/venelin/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer/AuthServer.cpp:37: undefined reference to `mysql_init'
/home/venelin/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer/AuthServer.cpp:40: undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect'
/home/venelin/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer/AuthServer.cpp:43: undefined reference to `mysql_query'
/home/venelin/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer/AuthServer.cpp:44: undefined reference to `mysql_store_result'
/home/venelin/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer/AuthServer.cpp:48: undefined reference to `mysql_num_fields'
/home/venelin/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer/AuthServer.cpp:50: undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_row'
/home/venelin/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer/AuthServer.cpp:70: undefined reference to `mysql_free_result'
/home/venelin/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer/AuthServer.cpp:73: undefined reference to `mysql_close'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeFiles/AuthServer.dir/build.make:104: recipe for target 'bin/AuthServer' failed
make[3]: *** [bin/AuthServer] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:209: recipe for target 'Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeFiles/AuthServer.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeFiles/AuthServer.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:216: recipe for target 'Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeFiles/AuthServer.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeFiles/AuthServer.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:164: recipe for target 'AuthServer' failed
make: *** [AuthServer] Error 2
```

In my root `CMakeLists.txt` I have the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(Vibranium_Core)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(Boost 1.72.0)

if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find boost!")
endif()
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")
find_package(MySQL REQUIRED)

include_directories(${MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/Common)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/Core/WorldServer)   
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/Core/AuthServer)

set_target_properties(
        Common WorldServer AuthServer
        PROPERTIES
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib"
        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib"
        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
)
```

In my `Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeLists.txt` I have the following:

```
if(WIN32)
    if(MSVC)
        list(APPEND PRIVATE_SOURCES AuthServer.rc)
    endif()
endif()

add_executable(AuthServer AuthServer.cpp ${PRIVATE_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(AuthServer LINK_PUBLIC Common)

if(NOT EXISTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs/)
    message(STATUS "Configs folder will be created: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs")
    file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs/)
endif()

if(NOT EXISTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs/AuthServer.conf)
message(STATUS "New AuthServer Config file in will be installed in: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs")
add_custom_command(
        TARGET AuthServer POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/AuthServer.conf.dist
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs/)
endif()
```

I have this installed:

```
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

What I understand is that is some sort of linking error. How Can I fix it however ?

Comment: Do you have a `target_link_libraries(AuthServer ${MYSQL_LIBRARY})` in your CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: In which one root or the one of AuthServer ?

Comment: Just add to the existing `target_link_libraries` command you already have?

Comment: Probably in `Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeLists.txt` although like @Someprogrammerdude mentioned you can add `${MYSQL_LIBRARY}` to your existing target_link_libraries